# How to apply changes to emacs .el files

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

How to apply changes to emacs .el files?

I've done the following:

1. `# locate buff-menu`

/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/buff-menu.el.gz
/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/buff-menu.elc

1. Modify `/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/buff-menu.el.gz` - add some custom letters in `Buffer-menu-select` doc section.
2. `# rm /usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/buff-menu.elc`
3. Byte compile `/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/buff-menu.el.gz`

Start emacs and see old description for `Buffer-menu-select`

Comment: are you sure you want to modify your system installed libraries?  those changes may get wiped out by a future system update.

Comment: jtahlborn: Attempt can be different, but the question remains nonetheless.

Comment: Are you sure that's your only copy of buff-menu? `locate` can get out of date, and what you describe should result in your modified buff-menu code getting run.

Comment: What does `M-x locate-library` tell you inside Emacs? You should also see in the `*Messages*` buffer where a library is being loaded from when you load it.

Comment: or `find-library` can take you there directly if you really need to edit the file (but again, you almost certainly don't).

Comment: `M-x locate-library` gives `/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/buff-menu.elc`. I've checked this file manually and found my modified strings. Also after `M-x load-file` `/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp/buff-menu.elc` I'm getting exactly what I want - a modified function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could more easily answer you if you tell us what exactly you want
to do. The fact is the correct way to customize Emacs is never to
change the .el in Emacs system libraries.

- to change a defun you can:

  - use an advice (look at the documentation of `defadvice`)
  - use a new `defun` that you will eval in an `eval-after-load`

    ```
    (eval-after-load 'buff-menu
       '(defun Buffer-menu-mark ()
           "do nothing"
           (interactive)))
    ```
- to add a key binding you can again use `eval-after-load`:

  ```
      (eval-after-load 'buff-menu
         '(define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map "M" 'Buffer-menu-mark))
  ```

Comment: I want to change the way of windows layout. When selecting 2 or more buffers in `*Buffer List*` window using `m` then typing `v` I've got all marked buffers with horizontal separator. But I want a vertical separators, or a matrix of windows.

Comment: After looking at the code source, you need to redefine
Buffer-menu-select, so use the second form I gave (advice seem to weak
with this example). In you .emacs add:


        (eval-after-load 'buff-menu
          '(defun Buffer-menu-select ()
             ……))

you "just" have to replace those … by the modified version

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the right and common way of extending and customizing the Emacs. I don't mind that it is common - to rewrite a default function totally.

Comment: Common I don't know, but elisp permit-it, and I had already used it. Well most of the time an advice is enough, but if not, I've no hesitation.